# Sulla pronuncia del nome Elena

Tags: pronunciation, name, proper-nouns

Ieri in Catalogna si è festeggiato [San Giorgio](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diada_de_Sant_Jordi). Si tratta della "festa"  delle rose e dei libri (non so se "festa" sia la parola più adeguata perché di solito questo giorno si lavora). È tradizionale comprare un libro (e anche una rosa alle donne) in questa data.

Parlando di possibili libri da acquistare per San Giorgio, ho voluto dire che io forse comprerei qualche romanzo di Elena Ferrante. Allora mi sono accorta di non saper come pronunciare il nome Elena: non sapevo se far la parola sdrucciola oppure piana. Ho cercato il [nome "Elena" sul Dizionario d’ortografia e di pronunzia della RAI](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=58975&r=1680), ma questo non ha chiarito il mio dubbio perché riporta tutte e due le possibilità di pronuncia,  "*èlena*" e anche "*elèna*":

[image: Elena nel DOP]
So che non si sa quasi nulla di Elena Ferrante, ma si conosce perlomeno la pronuncia che lei fa del suo pseudonimo (o nome)? Qual è il modo più frequente di pronunciare questo nome?

Comment: A nessun italiano contemporaneo verrebbe da dire “Elèna”; e direi che lo chiarisce anche la voce del DOP con l'inciso “nei poeti dal '300 al '600”.

Comment: Può darsi, @DaG, ma a me sembra di ricordare aver ascoltato un'italiana dire appunto "Elèna Ferrànte": questo fatto è quello che ha suscitato il mio dubbio.

Comment: Mi sembra davvero strano, @Charo. La pronuncia è senza dubbio sdrucciola.

Comment: Per esempio: [scrittori, giornalisti e altri che parlano di Elena Ferrante](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=elena+ferrante&page=&utm_source=opensearch) (come di qualsiasi altra Elena: non è il nome della Ferrante ad avere qualcosa di misterioso).

Comment: @DaG: Forse il problema in questi video di YouTube è che in quelli che sono in inglese si dice "Elèna" mentre che in quelli in italiano si pronuncia "Èlena" (perlomeno in alcuni che ho ascoltato io è così).

Comment: Mi riferivo a quelli in italiano, come quello con Lucarelli e altri, in effetti.

Comment: @DaG: Voglio dire che forse l'origine del dubbio è il fatto che, fuori d'Italia, questa scrittrice sia conosciuta come "Elèna Ferrànte". L'italiana che ho menzionato prima si stava esprimendo in italiano, ma parlava con gente di Barcellona (infatti, quest'italiana lavora da anni a Barcellona). Forse ha detto "Elèna Ferrànte" per farsi capire meglio dagli ascoltatori.

Comment: Ah, potrebbe essere. Conosco un Andrea (italiano, maschio), che all'estero si presenta come Andreas per evitare malintesi.

Comment: @Charo Vorrei solo aggiungere che, a giudicare dalle tre citazioni poetiche riportate dal dizionario, la pronuncia "Elèna" era dovuta anche a ragioni metriche (Guido Orlandi) e di rima.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La pronuncia contemporanea del nome Elena è sempre "Èlena". Si può facilmente notare come molti video in italiano su Elena Ferrante utilizzino questa pronuncia (esempi: Carlo Lucarelli https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8SxSBSOCYA; Antonio Monda https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RR7mtGjVm7Q), mentre la pronuncia "Elèna" viene utilizzata soprattutto da autori stranieri - in quanto più somigliante alla pronuncia di Elena e della variante Helena in inglese, spagnolo, greco - o da autori italiani di fronte ad un pubblico internazionale, magari all'estero.

Per quanto riguarda la pronuncia "Elèna", il suo impiego da parte dei poeti tra il XIV e il XVII secolo potrebbe essere semplicemente dovuto a ragioni metriche e di rima. Ad esempio, la prima citazione

> La reputò sì di bellezza piena,
>
> che la propose con seco ad Elena

formerebbe una rima baciata solo con la pronuncia "Elèna", e così via. Lo spostamento dell'accento per ragioni metriche e di rima è tipico della poesia, da Omero fino a certi testi rap attuali. Tra i tanti esempi, si può citare il primo verso delle Bucoliche di Virgilio :

> **Ti**tyre, **tu** patul**ae** recub**ans** sub **te**gmine **fa**gi

in cui *patulae* ha l'accento sull' ultima sillaba, a differenza della pronuncia corretta.

Questo spiegherebbe perché "Elena" venisse pronunciato alla greca, a differenza di altri nomi greci, come Alessandro, che invece non conservavano la pronuncia originale (in questo caso, Alèssandro, da Αλέξανδρος).

Comment: Personalmente, non tirerei in ballo Omero e Virgilio, perché la metrica classica non era accentuativa bensì quantitativa: si basava sulla posizioni reciproca delle sillabe lunghe e brevi e non degli accenti tonici. In altre parole, non è che un poeta greco o latino occasionalmente violasse gli accenti “naturali” delle parole per motivi metrici come può fare un poeta in volgare, è che non ne teneva proprio conto.

Comment: Forse non mi sono espresso con chiarezza. Volevo solo ricordare che, a mio giudizio, non si dovrebbe tenere in considerazione la pronuncia di un vocabolo all' interno di una poesia, perché questa può subire variazioni per ragioni di rima o metriche. L'esempio di Virgilio era solo, per così dire, un caso estremo, dovuto alla diversa concezione della metrica in epoca classica, ma questo non cambia la sostanza, e cioè che è possibile trovare vocaboli con una pronuncia non corretta all' interno di un testo poetico.

Comment: Siamo perfettamente d'accordo: solo, fossi stato in te semplicemente non avrei tirato in ballo la metrica quantitativa che è proprio diversa per sua natura e avrei viceversa ancor più accentuato (pun intended) il fatto che in quella accentuativa può succedere di violare gli accenti tonici.

Comment: Purtroppo non abbiamo altre occorrenze... Vedendo gli usi in poesia viene il sospetto che il nome fosse pronunciato nei due modi (Elèna per influsso del francese) e che "proprio per questo" sia stato scelto. Sono anch'io del parere che l'esempio tratto dalla poesia Latina non sia il più adatto.

Comment: Mi viene in mente che un altro caso di termine con doppia pronuncia (e quindi doppia possibilità metrica) è "oceano", solitamente pronunciato "ocèano", che in poesia è "oceàno".